# libvirt & openvswitch VLAN tagging on the fly

Tags: libvirt, virsh, openvswitch

I'm working on a project using libvirt with qemu and openvswitch on Debian 10.
I would like to be able to modify the configuration of a network card of a domain in bash with the update-device command of virsh.

For that I took an example from  [this article](https://netdevops.me/2017/changing-libvirt-bridge-attachment-in-a-running-domain-aka-on-the-fly/).

The initial configuration of the network interface is as follows:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <source bridge='waldorf0'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>
```

After the domain define and start, I get the mac address assigned to the interface and i product this file :

```
<interface type='bridge'>
   <mac address='52:54:XX:XX:XX:XX'/>
   <source bridge='waldorf0'/>
   <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
   <model type='virtio'/>
   <vlan>
       <tag id='2'/>
   </vlan>
 </interface>
```

After I execute this command :

```
virsh update-device domain int_conf.xml --live --persistent
```

It returns :

```
error: Failed to update device from int_conf.xml
error: Operation not supported: unnable to change config on 'bridge' network type
```

If you have an idea to work around this problem in order to dynamically tag vlan on interfaces.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What libvirt version? Is this a standard libvirt package from debian? Is that error message a direct copy of what you are seeing? It contains a typo 'unnable' which I don't see in libvirt git

Comment: I'm sorry I solved the problem. This was because the XML file I used with the update-device command accidentally deleted parameters. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. This was because the XML file I used with the update-device command accidentally deleted parameters. I use the dumpxml command to get the exact configuration of the interface.